# Jquery add row right below the selected row

Tags: jquery

I am working on this piece of codes. I wish to enable delete and add row for each single row. For the add row button, i wish to have the row added right below the selected row... anyone know how to do that?
Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src= 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

            var counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

            $("#ibtnDel").on("click", function () {
                counter = -1
            });

            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" id="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
            cols += '<td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" /></td>';


            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        });

        $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"]', function (event) {
            calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
            calculateGrandTotal();
        });


        $("table.order-list").on("click", "#ibtnDel", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            calculateGrandTotal();
        });

    });



    function calculateRow(row) {
        var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
    }

    function calculateGrandTotal() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
            grandTotal += +$(this).val();
        });
        $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price1" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" id="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="">Grand Total: $<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `$("table.order-list")` to `$("table.order-list tbody")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create `ids` and insert in `html DOM` which are similar and trying to add click event on `ids` which is really a bad practice and against the HTML rules!! So I've changed your click event by listening it to `class` and adding `class` to each button and below will be your changes:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lg0v4yyz/)**

```
$("#myTable").on("click",".addRow", function () {
      var counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";
      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="button" id="ibtnDel" class="dele" value="Delete"></td>';
      cols += '<td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" /></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      newRow.insertAfter($(this).parents().closest('tr'));
      counter++;
});
 $("#myTable").on("click",".dele", function () {
         counter = -1
 });
```

Delete functionality would be:

```
 $("table.order-list").on("click", ".dele", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            calculateGrandTotal();
 });
```

Use `.insertAfter` to insert right after the clicked row.

Comment: Please change $(document).on to $("#myTable").on and move the dele click outside the event handler too

Comment: You are still nesting the second $("#myTable").on("click",".dele"... It should be removed

Comment: @mplungjan.. Oops!! Now it's fine I guess.. :)

Answer (score 1):

### [>> WORKING DEMO <<](http://jsfiddle.net/2e76jno6/)

Visualisation of demo:

[image]

I saw that in all the other answers the `count` functionality is totally ignored and hence doesn't work anymore in their posted demos. Therefore the `add` buttons are never disabled.

I have solved this problem by making sure that the code is coherent everywhere. As you can see from my demo, all `add` buttons are disabled when the count variable is equal to 4. Also, all buttons are enabled again when the count function goes below 4 again. This is probably exactly what you intended.

What you needed to do to make the selective addition function was to add another function which takes care of adding rows after the row on which the corresponding button was clicked.

As an example:

### jQuery

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnAdd"  value="Add after"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    if (counter >= 4) {
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $('.ibtnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    }
    counter++;
});

// ...
// ... here is the other jQuery code
// ...

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    calculateGrandTotal();
    counter--;
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
    $('.ibtnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add after");
});

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnAdd", function (event) {
    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnAdd" value="Add after"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel" value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $(this).closest("tr").after(newRow);
    if (counter >= 4) {
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $('.ibtnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    }
    counter++;
});
```

Also, it is recommendable to use `.after()` instead of `.append()`.

Good luck!

Comment: Cool vid. How did you record it?

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks! There is an awesome little program for this called `ScreenToGif`. You can [**download it here**](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). It has an extremely easy-to-use interface and I always enjoy using it. When the gif has been recorded, simply add it to your question/answer as a normal picture.

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/gax0w07p/

Use of `.after()` instead of `append`:

```
 //Replace
 //$("table.order-list").append(newRow);
 // With
 $(this).parent().parent().after(newRow);
 // this = button
 // first parent = td
 // second parent = tr
```

another option is to use closest instead of two parent calls

```
 $(this).closest('tr').after(newRow);
```

**Documentation on `after()`:** http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/